# Golang: net.ParseIP()

Tags: go, ipv6

some perfectly valid IPv6 addresses are considered IPv4 by net.ParseIP(), e.g. 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0100:0000 / ::ffff:0100:0. (please see https://play.golang.org/p/57jAJVSIrHF for a simple example)

What would be the most idiomatic way to deal with this situation? The net package does not export most of the functionality, so rewriting net.Parse would result in a lot of code duplication.

Thank you in advance for your help!

best regards,

Stefan

Comment: Deal with what situation? What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you consider perfectly valid IPv6 addresses like `::ffff:0100:0000` are in fact IPv4 addresses mapped into the IPv6 space, commonly written as `::ffff:1.0.0.0`. Thus essentially it is an IPv4 address. See section about [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses in Wikipedia:IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Transition_mechanisms) for more information.

Comment: Oooops, i might be missing some basic understanding:

is 

::ffff:0100:000

 really the same as 

::ffff:1.0.0.0 ? I am aware of the notation using '.', but I am not sure if it is a IPv4-mapped IPv6 address when there are ':'?

Comment: @StefanBeyer: yes, `::ffff:0100:0000` is the same as `::ffff:1.0.0.0`. All `::ffff:0:0` are IPv4-mapped IPv6 and in this case the last 4 bytes (i.e. the IPv4 address) are commonly written as IPv4 syntax to make this mapping more obvious. To also cite from the Wikipedia article I've linked to: *"These addresses are typically written with a 96-bit prefix in the standard IPv6 format, and the remaining 32 bits written in the customary dot-decimal notation of IPv4."*

Comment: Ok, I see. 

You are right, the first sentence clearly states "These addresses consist of an 80-bit prefix of zeros, the next 16 bits are ones, and the remaining, least-significant 32 bits contain the IPv4 address" - it does  not mention . or : 

Thank you so much for your help!! Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) provides more fine-grained control over IPv4-mapped addresses (and other schemes for mapping IPv4 to IPv6).  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
addrStr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString("::ffff:0100:0")
addr := addrStr.GetAddress()
converter := ipaddr.DefaultAddressConverter{}
var ipv4Addr *ipaddr.IPv4Address
if converter.IsIPv4Convertible(addr) {
    ipv4Addr = converter.ToIPv4(addr)
}
fmt.Printf("original IPv4-mapped IPv6 address is %v, IPv4 address is %v",
    addr, ipv4Addr)
```

Output:

```
original IPv4-mapped IPv6 address is ::ffff:100:0, IPv4 address is 1.0.0.0
```